# How to make Django dictionary serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So i tried to make a serializer but my server keeps giving me this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
> return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
> response = self.handle_exception(exc)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
> self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
> raise exc
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
> response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\aldya\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\work\SmartTeens\proshop_django\base\views\marathon_views.py", line 56, in getMarathon
> marathon = Marathon.objects.get(_id=pk)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
> return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 418, in get
> clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
> return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
> clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
> self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
> clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in *add_q
> child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1319, in build_filter
> condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
> lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in **init**
> self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 76, in get_prep_lookup
> return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
> File "C:\Users\aldya.virtualenvs\proshop_django-fBhdlF-V\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_*init**.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
> raise e.**class**(
> ValueError: Field '_id' expected a number but got 'category'.

I'm accessing the getTopMarathonsByCategory method but somehow it keeps going to the getMarathons and asking for _id. This is the methods.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getTopMarathonsByCategory(request):
    categories = Category.objects.order_by('count')[0:5]
    serializer = MarathonCategorySerializer(categories, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getMarathon(request, pk):
    marathon = Marathon.objects.get(_id=pk)
    serializer = MarathonSerializer(marathon, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

And this is the serializers

```
class MarathonReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MarathonReview
        fields = '__all__'

class MarathonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    reviews = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Marathon
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_reviews(self, obj):
        reviews = obj.marathonreview_set.all()
        serializer = MarathonReviewSerializer(reviews, many=True)
        return serializer.data

class MarathonCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    marathon_set = MarathonSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('label','marathon_set')
```

I can't figure out what is wrong, could anybody help me?

Edit: Here's the url patterns:

```
from django.urls import path
from base.views import marathon_views as views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.getMarathons, name="marathons"),

    path('create/', views.createMarathon, name="marathon-create"),
    path('upload/', views.uploadImage, name="image-upload"),

    path('<str:pk>/reviews/', views.createMarathonReview, name="create-review"),
    path('top/', views.getTopMarathons, name='top-marathons'),
    path('<str:pk>/', views.getMarathon, name="marathon"),

    path('update/<str:pk>/', views.updateMarathon, name="marathon-update"),
    path('delete/<str:pk>/', views.deleteMarathon, name="marathon-delete"),

    path('category/', views.getTopMarathonsByCategory, name='category-marathons')
]
```

Comment: share your urls.py

Comment: from base.views import marathon_views as views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.getMarathons, name="marathons"),
path('create/', views.createMarathon, name="marathon-create"),path('upload/', views.uploadImage, name="image-upload"),
path('<str:pk>/reviews/', views.createMarathonReview, name="create-review"),
path('top/', views.getTopMarathons, name='top-marathons'),
    path('<str:pk>/', views.getMarathon, name="marathon"),

    path('update/<str:pk>/', views.updateMarathon, name="marathon-update"),
    path('delete/<str:pk>/', views.deleteMarathon, name="marathon-delete"),
]

Comment: oh bro, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67657635/edit) your post and add this to it

Comment: you didn't include the `getTopMarathonsByCategory` to your url patterns

Comment: I did edited it, thanks for the tip! I still can't figure out what's the problem